# Why do I get an ambiguous function error from this? the function arguments are clearly different

Tags: c++

```
#include "iostream"

void func(int Y)
{
    std::cout << Y;
}


void func(float X)
{
    std::cout << X;
}

int main()
{
    func(5);

    func(5.0);
}
```

When I switch the argument type from float to double this works I get no errors. is the compiler treating float as int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`5.0` is a `double` not a `float`, so both functions are an equal match.

Use `5.0f` for `float`.